# TFS 2015 build definition "Get Version"

Tags: build, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, build-definition

In a XAML build definition, there was a parameter "Get Version".
([Example](http://blog.sublogic.com/2011/09/22/tfs-2010-building-an-older-changeset))

I couldn't find the same functionality in the new TFS 2015 build system, nor on Visual Studio Online / Visual Studio Team Services.

As an alternative, I could make a branch from a specific version and build that, but this seems like a dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not support for VNext build now. There has been a **feature request** in **UserVoice**, you can vote up to make it gets more attention.

> Specify Changeset or Label to build from on vNext (TFS 2015) builds.
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10774335-specify-changeset-or-label-to-build-from-on-vnext

Answer (score 1):

For VSO/VSTS, you can enter the version when queue a new build:
[image]